# Communication between a C# and Python application hosted on the same machine

Tags: c#, python, interface, tcp, communication

We're working on a project that requires us to interface with a specific set of hardware; one set can be controlled very easily using C#, the other of which is natively programmed using Python. Part of the project involves getting the hardware running on Python to communicate with the hardware running through C#, and unfortunately, due to time constraints, we aren't able to create a set of C# or Python software to control the other set of hardware.

The set of hardware running on Python is completely event based, in that we can program functions that are called when certain conditions are met by the hardware. Our thought was to modify the C# application controlling the other set of hardware to host the Python application (using something like `Application.Run()`), then program the Python functions to propagate relevant data to the C# application as the events come in from the hardware.

We're considering using a socket connection to handle communication between the two, as both C# and Python are fairly simple to get working that way (or so our Python guy claims). The biggest concern with this that we have is if there will be any issues with the fact that both programs will be hosted on the same machine. If this won't be an issue, we would probably end up using a shared library such as [0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/)

We've also done some research into the following areas:

- Pipes / Named Pipes
- Message Queues
- Shared Memory

Basically we want to know which method of these (or any others) will be the easiest to implement with these languages, and which will give us the best performance. We are concerned only with **speed** and **accuracy** of the data (ie, if using network packets, one that will drop the least). Security is not a concern.

Ideally, there should be one data stream going from the Python application to the C# application, and two data streams going from the the C# application to the Python application. The host machine will be running Windows 7. I can give additional information as needed.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to try [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/). Since IronPython is a .NET language, communicating with C# code should be easy.

It seems worth looking into how hard it would be to get your existing Python code running on IronPython.